# How to get reflection class and reflection function in logger

Tags: java, selenium, logging, automation

I want to display name of the class and function under class(which is running) when output is displayed in below logger code. What should i do to reflect function and class
Below is code:

```
Logger.getLogger("results").log(new LogRecord(Level.INFO, "Reflection Function. Reflection class, "
                + ((msg.isEnabled() && text.contains("Successfully update database."))?"success":"failure")));
```

Please help to solve this issue

Comment: You mean print each event the code?

Comment: Check log4j implementation, hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Don't use a "logger", instead use a library like JUnit or TestNG and turn these `if-then` statements into `Assert`s. Then add relevant validation strings and you'll have the log you want without having to dig through all the passes to find just the fails.

Comment: Thanks! But for some time being i will use the logger but i will keep this mind and will try for sure but now other question is i want to use reflection class and function in logger